# Magic is channeled through playing instruments. How are fights fought?

Tags: magic

In my world, magic can be channeled through instruments with the proper components. How would street-level brawls be fought with this magic, seeing as each spell takes time to do? The stronger the spell, the longer the musical piece. Time period is modern day.

Comment: "The devil went down to Georgia. He was looking for a soul to steal..."

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding @Silfer274! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Unfortunately your question as it is currently written is rather broad, and opinion based.

Comment: I'm assuming something along the lines of this? With a little bit more magic? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvipPYFebWc

Comment: The sharper the musician, the sharper their instrument, the deadly the magic. Fast riffs on wicked guitars with blades on the outer edges of the body. Great visuals, might not be what you are after though. Or! The magic can be directed in an arc from the blade, or focused through the headstock like a magical laser. I prefer particle cannons, but that's just me.

Comment: What fight we are talking about here? Bar(d)-brawl? War? Does the magic launch projectile? Can there be friendly-fire?

Comment: What are limitations of your magic? Can a child invoke a spell by just messing up with appropriate instruments? Does a type of an instrument affect spells? Do spells follow the same rules as music?

Comment: This was a mechanic in the classic MMO Dark Age of Camelot.  Music could be used to stun opponents, charm animals to fight for you, and make your party run faster.

Comment: @Henry Taylor:"24 karat magic in the air
Head to toe so player
Uh, look out!"

Comment: unless you define how music makes magic and what the rules are in your universe this ends up being way to broad an opinion based.

Comment: Alan Dean Foster's Spellsinger series is a kind of fun application here

Comment: **"The stronger the spell, the longer the musical piece. Time period is modern day."** It might take an entire day to set up the stage and do the sound checks for a "*Yes*" show. This also means people should stay away from Glastonbury during the music festival.....

Comment: I agree that this is broad, but not unworkably so.  Slifer274, can you add some specifics with an Edit?  Linitations you think might be appropriate, or an end goal for the mage?

Comment: @Thucydides You could get an entire space program out of David Bowie, Rush, and Yes =)  No need for NASA, just Prog Rock!

Comment: you should read a novel called silent crown on webnovel.com you will find exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 5):

Combining the idea of a wind instrument with a staff. A large, stout hollow staff swung rapidly cold make whistling or other noises (think of a [Didgeridoo](https://infogalactic.com/info/Didgeridoo), for example).

[image]

*Steel reinforcing hoops around the ends would also make these effective as non magical weapons*

A whistle built into a steel weight attached to a chain and swung in circles of varying size could also be used to make a spell, and the weight and chain makes an effective way of attacking or blocking physical attacks (entangling a sword for example). The Japanese [Kusarigama](https://infogalactic.com/info/Kusarigama) could serve as an example.

[image]

*Preparing a Kusarigama for use*

Finally, magic cam be used as an adjunct to regular forces. The earliest well documented example is actually the ancient Spartans marching to battle in time to flutes:

> And when at last they were drawn up in battle array and the enemy was at hand, the king sacrificed the customary she-goat, commanded all the warriors to set garlands upon their heads, and ordered the pipers to pipe the strains of the hymn to Castor; 3 then he himself led off in a marching paean, and it was a sight equally grand and terrifying when they marched in step with the rhythm of the flute, without any gap in their line of battle, and with no confusion in their souls, but calmly and cheerfully moving with the strains of their hymn into the deadly fight. Neither fear nor excessive fury is likely to possess men so disposed,  p277 but rather a firm purpose full of hope and courage, believing as they do that Heaven is their ally.

*Plutarch • Life of Lycurgus verse 22.3*

[image]

*Spartans "moving with the strains of their hymn into the deadly fight"*

So combining musical instruments with devices which can be converted to weapons, or marching into battle with musicians seems to provide the most effective way of using music to create magic in a battle.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, throwing a fireball, that can incinerate a castle gate, takes a pianist, two guitars and a complete brass section.  Sure the spell's score spans four full movements of several hundred measures each.  It is an incredibly difficult spell which should only be attempted by master musicians; but how often do you need to burn down a castle gate?

For street fights,  [quick licks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lick_(music)) are the name of the game.  A good street musician can burn an opponent's skin in three measures.  The best can blind in half a measure; eight lightning quick sixteenth notes to push the light out of their victim's eyes.  The magic doesn't care about the metre.  If you race through the notes, and get them all right, the magic will still come.

There is a legend of a drummer who can kill with single beat.  Don't mess with drummers on the street!  They're deadly.

Comment: My goodness, can you imagine the damage that could be done by Diablo String Orchestra or Epica?!?!  Entire cities leveled in the space of one album!

Comment: I can imagine the damage done during rehearsals...  You have to practice at least once with 'real' instruments before you can be brought to a battlefield.

Comment: "There is a legend of a drummer who can kill with single beat. Don't mess with drummers on the street! They're deadly." So you finally explained what happened to the drummers of "*Spinal Tap*"!

Comment: Can I give rep boosts for comments @Thucydides?  That's hilarious

Comment: @PaulTIKI, Thucydides posted an answer to this question.  Just do what I did and upvote his answer.

Comment: I already did @HenryTaylor.  But these comments are too much fun and deserve more :)

Comment: These comments need to become more selective: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZ6JxAgmxXg

Answer (score 1):

Wait, are you talking about...

## [The Battle of the Bands](https://youtu.be/cvvWpv6uB8s)?

On a more serious note, interrupting and protecting the musicians becomes the main priorities when fighting or using this magic. Shields, compact instruments, and annoying distractions are all good here.

Alternatively, you can think of musicians as artillery: keep them away from the sounds of battle and have them deliver mighty magical motifs from a distance. Or conceal them and have magic spells suddenly appear.

Answer (score 1):

So what you have is magic that is based around sound, but magic is almost always bound to thought as well.  Some worlds have spells that require moonbeams, instead, yours will require an "A" chord.

Down to brass tacks.  The first aspect is to define what kinds of physical components.  I'm going to imagine a guitar for this.  You could have it require a specific wood for the neck and frets, to channel the magic out.  Rosewood is common in mundane instruments I think, but I don't know exactly why. Maybe investigate why, choose a similar but more rare wood for the magical variety.  Next, the body.  A guitar body is shaped like it is because it resonates is a special way.  Change the shape or line it with steel like a Dobro guitar for magical resonance.  Finally, the Strings.  Coat them with gold or other precious metals.  Really you can do what you like.  Just put some reasoning behind it.

Next, the Music.  Most songs are composed to illicit a response from the listener.  The bands Five Finger Death Punch or Disturbed tend to write angry songs.  That anger, with added magic could generate fireballs.  Simon and Garfunkle songs could draw out a torpor in it's victims.  I have no idea what Skrillex would do...maybe a twitching seizure.  Again, a little logic here goes a long way.

That's all background, now for the actual answer about Combat apllications.  Maybe you could think of specific chords as quick and dirty  violent projections.  not too specific, slightly directional, and as risky to the caster as the enemy.  Maybe a specific repeating group of musical phrases could generate a shield for the group to resist some sort of onslaught, or deflect bullets.  Breaking the tune breaks the spell.  A quiet song gives stealth abilities.  Not invisibility, but inattention.  A complete song could produce a specific and more complex result.  Cracking a safe maybe.  Disturbed's "The Light" would be a great healing song. Who knows?

As in a great many stories and games, your wizard is probably going to be support for a larger group.  Lower HP and needing protection. The Author Stephen Brust said it best, "Not matter how powerful the Wizard or Subtle the Mage, a dagger between the shoulder blades will seriously cramp his style"